# How get info from <span>

Tags: javascript, html

I want to get the text "0:56" from span from the site. How can i do this?

```
<div class="vjs-current-time vjs-time-control vjs-control">
    <span class="vjs-control-text">Current Time&nbsp;</span>
    <span class="vjs-current-time-display" aria-live="off">0:56</span>
</div>
```

I tried `var currentTime = document.getElementsByClassName("vjs-current-time-display");`

But I don't think this is the right way.

Comment: "But I don't think this is the right way" - why do you think that? What else did you try to resolve the problem?

Answer (score 1):

In your example you will get a HTMLCollection. It means you have to use a key to receive the element.  `const data = document.getElementsByClassName("vjs-current-time-display")[0];`

But if you know that you have only once then you can use the querySelector and then with innerText or InnerHTML you can fetch the data. Try this:

```js
const data1 = document.querySelector('.vjs-current-time .vjs-current-time-display').innerText
console.log('querySelector:', data1);

const data2 = document.getElementsByClassName("vjs-current-time-display")[0].innerHTML;
console.log('getElementsByClassName:',data2);
```

```html
<div class="vjs-current-time vjs-time-control vjs-control">
    <span class="vjs-control-text">Current Time&nbsp;</span>
    <span class="vjs-current-time-display" aria-live="off">0:56</span>
</div>
```

If you have multiple elements with times then you can use `getElementsByClassName` or `querySelectorAll`. Afterwards you have to iterate them.